# Can anyone identify this stopper knot?

Tags: knot-identification

I was trying to tie a largish stopper knot using a guide on my phone. Somehow I ended up with this.

It works for what I wanted but I’d like to know its name.

[image: Knot]

Answer (score 9):

This is what people in my area refer to as the "stopper knot," i.e., the most common knot used around here for that purpose: a double overhand. It just isn't dressed in the standard way. Knots are often hard to identify when they're not dressed the way we're used to seeing them dressed.

[image: dressing a stopper knot]

Comment: Specifically, a double-overhand knot.  Also known as *blood knot* or *barrel knot*; probably has other names, too.

Comment: @TobySpeight: Double overhand seems like the most logical name, although I've never actually heard anybody in my area call it anything but a stopper. It would  be nice if knot terminology were more logical and systematic, but unfortunately people look at you blankly if you say "offset overhand" rather than "euro death knot."

Comment: It's just odd to hear it called "the" stopper knot, as if no other kind of stopper knot existed.  Especially as the question is "*what kind of stopper knot is this?*"  It's a bit like saying something is "a hitch" - describing the purpose, but not identifying the knot.

Comment: doesn't that look a lot like a clove hitch?

Comment: @njzk2, superficially yes, in that it has two turns.  But the topology is very different (you can see that the working ends exit the knot in totally different places, compared to the clove hitch).  Tie them both yourself and see the difference!  Notice that the clove hitch totally unravels when there's nothing inside it (that's why it's a hitch and not a stopper!)

Comment: @Ben, for me (more of a caver than anything else right now) the most common stopper knots I'll use are overhand loop (for abseil ropes, where I might need to cowstail into it and add an extension) or single overhand (to minimise the rope used in the knot).

Comment: @TobySpeight indeed. Although tying this stopper knot around a pole ends up looking quite close to a clove hitch, with just a single twist between the 2 ends

Comment: Thank you all for the comments! I didn’t know my knot was undressed in public. How embarrassing.